# What is inside $W \cap W^{\bot_{\phi}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, bilinear-form

I'm confused about this.

Consider a bilinear symmetric form $\phi :V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and its associated quadratic form $Q$. Then considering a generic vector subspace $W\subseteq V$, what is exactly inside the vector subspace $W \cap W^{\bot}$? Of course if $\phi$ is positive definite $W \cap W^{\bot}= \big\{ \vec{o} \big\}$.

But if $\phi$ is semipositive or indefinite can I say that
$W \cap W^{\bot}= \big\{ \vec{x} \in W |  \phi(\vec{x},\vec{x})=0 \big\}$?

(In this case $W \cap W^{\bot}$ is a subspace of the set of the isotropic vectors $\mathscr{I}$ )

But are there only those vectors? Is it better to write that

$$W \cap W^{\bot}= \big\{ \vec{x} \in W |  \phi(\vec{x},\vec{y})=0, \forall \vec{y} \in W\big\}?$$

And what are the difference between these two sets? Which is the right one?

What I think is that I can only say that $W \cap W^{\bot} \supseteq \big\{ \vec{x} \in W |  \phi(\vec{x},\vec{x})=0 \big\}$  because there could be other vectors with respect to wich $\vec{x}$ must be orthogonal, besides himself for $\vec{x}$ to be in $W \cap W^{\bot}$ but I can't really understand if this is right.

Answer (score 1):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (which also holds for semidefinite bilinear forms), we have
$$|\phi(x,y)|^2 \le \phi(x,x) \, \phi(y,y).$$
Hence,
$$\{x \in W : \phi(x,x) = 0\} = \{x \in W : \phi(x,y) = 0 \; \forall y \in W\}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are you considering that $\ker\phi \cap W=\big\{ \vec{x} \in W |  \phi(\vec{x},\vec{y})=0, \forall \vec{y} \in W\big\}?$ If so is the set that you wrote equal to $W\cap W^{\bot}$?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{ker}\phi$? The set in the last line of my answer is $W \cap W^\perp$.